# Swift 4 Mapview is not calling delegate method f

Tags: swift, annotations, delegates, mapkit

I try to present a view controller when user taps an enemy 50meters from my location with tutorial from (https://www.raywenderlich.com/151817/how-to-make-an-app-like-pokemon-go). But my viewcontroller does not show and I think I am not calling my delegate method from extension. How do i fix it?
This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
class GoogleMapsViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var targets = [Item]()
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var userLocation: CLLocation?
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: 0)!
        mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode(rawValue: 2)!
        setupLocations()        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        // Check for Location Services

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()

        }

    } 

    func setupLocations() {
        let pdpk = Item( Place : "Pildammsparken", location: CLLocation(latitude: 55.590105, longitude:  12.988737))
        targets.append(pdpk)
        let btp = Item( Place : "Bulltoftaparken", location: CLLocation(latitude: 55.601326, longitude:  13.079005))
        targets.append(btp) for item in targets {
            let annotation = MapA(location: item.location.coordinate, item: item)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        defer { userLocation = locations.last }

        if userLocation == nil {
            // Zoom to user location
            if let uLocation = locations.last {
                let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(uLocation.coordinate, 2000, 2000)
                mapView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: false)
                print(uLocation)

            }

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension GoogleMapsViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        self.userLocation = userLocation.location
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        //1
        let coordinate = view.annotation!.coordinate
        //2
        if let userCoordinate = userLocation {
            //3
            if userCoordinate.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)) < 50 {
                //4
                print("test")
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ARViewController") as?    PlaceViewController {
                    // more code later
                    //5
                    if let mapAnnotation = view.annotation as? MapA {
                        //6
                        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set in `viewDidLoad`

```
mapView.delegate = self
```

Comment: This worked! I've seen this other places, what precisely does this do?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the delegate in two ways

1. Through Code `mapview.delegate = self`
2. Through the interface builder. By connecting the mapview's delegate with the viewcontroller. Reference screenshot is attached

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sh_Khan is absolutely correct.

You can also control drag to the view controller icon on the left and choose "delegate" from the popup menu. You can also set the data source for objects like tables, pickers, etc.